# How to read Xml File Using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I'm having an XML file like

```
<root>
  <Child val1="1" val2="2"/>
  <Child val1="3" val2="4"/>
  <Child val1="5" val2="6"/>
  <Child val1="7" val2="8"/>
  <Child val1="9" val2="10"/>
  <Child val1="11" val2="12"/>
  <Child val1="13" val2="14"/>
</root>
```

i need to read the attribute values of `val1` and `val2` to a `List<String>`

the resulting list will contain

```
{ "1" , "2" , "3" , ........ ,"13" , "14" }
```

Here is my sample code:

```
XDocument XD = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\foo.xml");
List<String> l_lstTemp = XD.Descendants("Child")
                           .Select(X => new List<String> { X.Attribute("val1").Value,
                                                           X.Attribute("val2").Value })
                           .SelectMany(X => X)
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

is there any way to do this using `Select` instead of `selectMany`?

How to modify my existing `expression`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectMany` is doing exactly what you want here - it's flattening the result from a sequence of lists of strings to a single sequence of strings. Why would you want to take working code which expresses exactly what you need and change it?

Admittedly you can simplify it somewhat by using `SelectMany` slightly differently, and using an array instead of a list to shorten things a bit too::

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\foo.xml");
List<String> values = doc.Descendants("Child")
                         .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.Attribute("val1").Value,
                                                  x.Attribute("val2").Value })
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem scenario is exactly what SelectMany is there for so I think anything we might try to do to eliminate it would just complicate things. :)

The initial .Select is returning a result of IEnumerable's and without the .SelectMany we'd get:

```
{
 IEnumerable<string> [ "1", "2" ]
 IEnumerable<string> [ "3", "4" ]
 etc...
}
```

.SelectMany takes an IEnumerable will 'flatten' the initial results into another IEnumerable leaving you with what you want:

```
{
 IEnumerable<string> [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ]
}
```

Here is a great post with a much better description [A Visual Look at the LINQ SelectMany Operator](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/03/12/A-Visual-Look-At-The-LINQ-SelectMany-Operator.aspx).